# Discord bot problem "is a required argument that is missing"

Tags: python, bots, discord, discord.py

so basically I'm trying to make a youtube player command that will play audio through a voice chat and I've been testing the command and it keeps saying "dysfunctional (name of variable) is a required argument that is missing" and I am providing the link but it still says its missing, I may just be dumb but I'm almost positive this should be working

```
@client.command(pass_context=True)
async def yt(self, ctx,*, dysfunctional):
    channel = ctx.message.author.voice.voice_channel
    if dysfunctional.startswith('https://www.youtube.com'):
        voice = await client.join_voice_channel(channel)
        player = await voice.create_ytdl_player(dysfunctional)
        player.start()
    if dysfunctional == "stop":
        player.stop()
        disconnect()
```

Comment: Is this in a class?  Usually we see `self` in cogs, but the decorator you're using makes that unlikely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You arent in a cog class and so you don't get the self parameter. Try with the following code

```
@client.command(pass_context=True)
async def yt(ctx, *, dysfunctional):
    channel = ctx.message.author.voice.voice_channel
    if dysfunctional.startswith('https://www.youtube.com'):
        voice = await client.join_voice_channel(channel)
        player = await voice.create_ytdl_player(dysfunctional)
        player.start()
    if dysfunctional == "stop":
        player.stop()
        disconnect()
```